# How can I modify a node's attributes in a shell script?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

I have been editing node's by using knife node edit [node_name] however, I'd like to save some time and write a script that will automate adding an attribute set to many nodes manifests.

I'd like some way to add the following into the "normal": {} section in a bash script.

```
"borg": {
  "client": {
    "backup_server_override": "10.140.4.141"
  }
},
```

Is there a command, or way I can do this without using knife node edit, and avoiding the interactive editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `knife exec` and `nodes.transform`, probably will do what you want:

```
knife exec -E 'nodes.transform ("*:*") {|n| n.normal["whatever"] = "something" }'
```

**WARNING: `"*:*"` will grab ALL nodes and applies the transform function to them. Be careful.**

Comment: This works great. How would I add attributes to ["whatever"], I'd like to do something like this:   "normal": { "whatever": { "more": { "apple": "orange"}}} }

Comment: `n.normal['whatever']['more']['apple'] = 'orange'`, just like in cookbook code.

Comment: I messed around and came up with something that works: /usr/local/bin/knife exec -E 'nodes.transform ("*:some_node") {|n| n.normal_attrs["whatever"] = {"test1"=>{"test1" =>"123456"}};}';